# R Installation of Package 'Rcpp' had Non-Zero Exit Status

Tags: r

I am trying to run a package called Harmony on R in Jupyter Notebooks using the following lines of code:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("immunogenomics/harmony")
```

However, I get an error message reading:

```
Installing 45 packages: Rcpp, dplyr, tidyr, ggplot2, Matrix, tibble, rlang, SingleCellExperiment, RcppArmadillo, RcppProgress, cli, fansi, lifecycle, pillar, vctrs, glue, digest, isoband, scales, testthat, farver, R6, lattice, rstudioapi, callr, prettyunits, backports, processx, ps, tidyselect, BH, GenomicRanges, Biobase, DelayedArray, BiocGenerics, S4Vectors, IRanges, GenomeInfoDb, matrixStats, BiocParallel, RCurl, XVector, zlibbioc, stringi, SummarizedExperiment
Error: Failed to install 'harmony' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package 'Rcpp' had non-zero exit status
Traceback:

1. install_github("immunogenomics/harmony")
2. pkgbuild::with_build_tools({
 .     ellipsis::check_dots_used(action = getOption("devtools.ellipsis_action", 
 .         rlang::warn))
 .     {
 .         remotes <- lapply(repo, github_remote, ref = ref, subdir = subdir, 
 .             auth_token = auth_token, host = host)
 .         install_remotes(remotes, auth_token = auth_token, host = host, 
 .             dependencies = dependencies, upgrade = upgrade, force = force, 
 .             quiet = quiet, build = build, build_opts = build_opts, 
 .             build_manual = build_manual, build_vignettes = build_vignettes, 
 .             repos = repos, type = type, ...)
 .     }
 . }, required = FALSE)
3. install_remotes(remotes, auth_token = auth_token, host = host, 
 .     dependencies = dependencies, upgrade = upgrade, force = force, 
 .     quiet = quiet, build = build, build_opts = build_opts, build_manual = build_manual, 
 .     build_vignettes = build_vignettes, repos = repos, type = type, 
 .     ...)
4. tryCatch(res[[i]] <- install_remote(remotes[[i]], ...), error = function(e) {
 .     stop(remote_install_error(remotes[[i]], e))
 . })
5. tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
6. tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
7. value[[3L]](cond)
```

I am wondering why the installation of package Rcpp has a non-zero exit status and how I can resolve this to install my original package.

Comment: Try `brew install gcc`

Comment: @JimChen I tried that but the error remains the same

Comment: Your actual issue is that installation fails for Rcpp. Try to install Rcpp on its own (using install.packages) and look at/share the output.

Comment: @Roland the output of install.packages("Rcpp") is: Warning message in install.packages("Rcpp"):
"installation of package 'Rcpp' had non-zero exit status"Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done

Comment: There should be much more output from the compiler.

Comment: @Roland that is the only output for install.packages("Rcpp"). Maybe the issue is somewhere in addition to that?

Comment: What is your OS and your R version? Is it trying to install from source? I think it is because I don't think I've ever seen this error when installing binaries. If it installs from source there should be compiler output (or an error about problems with the compiler).

Comment: Also, try in Rgui.

Comment: @Roland I am using mac os catalina version 10.15.3 and my R version isn 3.6.1